# Create a 2D array of panels that each draw their own shape based on the classes designed previously

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I am creating a game that allows one player to move around a board with user input by the arrow keys on the keyboard. The objective is to collect the gems on the board and avoid the monsters that move around randomly. I am having issues just getting my board to be drawn in the GUI. Each "tile", "item", and "character" are drawn with simple, generic draw methods like drawRect and drawOval. However, I don't know how to get these to be drawn in an array of panels.

Is my issue in the constructor or the paint method? Help!

```
public class LevelPanel extends JPanel {
    private static Player player;
    private Level level;
    private JLabel gemLabel, scoreLabel, healthLabel;
    private JPanel[][] squares;
    private JPanel boardPanel;
    private JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();

    public LevelPanel() {
        this.player = player;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

    gemLabel = new JLabel("Gems Left: 0");
    scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: 0");
    healthLabel = new JLabel("Health: 100");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        squares[i][j] = new JPanel();
        squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
        boardPanel.add(squares[i][j]);
        }
    }

    add(gemLabel);
    add(scoreLabel);
    add(healthLabel);
    add(boardPanel);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
    level.draw(g);
    }

    private class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        switch(keyCode) { 
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            player.move(-1,0);
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            player.move(1,0);
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            player.move(0,-1);
            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: 
            player.move(0,1);
            break;
        }
        gemLabel.setText("Gems Left: " + level.getNumGems());
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + player.getScore());
        healthLabel.setText("Health: " + player.getHealth());
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: do not override `paint(..)` rather override `paintComponent(..)` of `JPanel`

Answer (score 1):

You never instantiate `squares` or `boardPanel`:

```
private JPanel[][] squares = new JPanel[10][10];
private JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel();
```

Also `level` in class `LevelPanel` does not appear to be instantiated. In this class also, you are assigning an undefined reference to `player`

```
public LevelPanel() {
    this.player = player;
```

You could pass in a `Player` reference:

```
public LevelPanel(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `JPanel[]` you can use `JButton[]` without any name with background color.

Here is an game example which is similar to your 2D Array need
[Shuffling JButton in CardLayout](http://javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-shuffle-game)

Comment: Thanks! I switched to an array of JButtons, but now I'm getting a NPE.                                                          squares = new JButton[level.getSize()][level.getSize()];
  for(int i = 0; i < level.getSize(); i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < level.getSize(); j++) {
    squares[i][j] = new JButton();
    boardPanel.add(squares[i][j]);
   }
  }

Comment: @user1850008 this is because `level` has not been instantiated. Neither has `squares`.